# CSS min-height on canvas (or even svg) has a limit?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html5-canvas

#### The Use case

Let's said you've a couple of `<div>` in 2 nested flex (one for column, the other for rows), in order to get something like:

[image]

You can resize the parent `<div>`, in any direction, and everything works as expected.

note `<div>` are defined with

```css
{
   /* flex: 1 1 0px */
   flex-grow: 1
   flex-shrink: 1
   flex-basis: 0px /* i.e. independant of content */
}
```

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  body {
    padding-left: 30px
  }
  
  span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px
  }
  
  #dut {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <span id="info"></span>
  <div style="
        background-color: gray;
        height: 200px;
        width: 50%;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;" onresize="onResize()">

    <div style="
            height:100%;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        ">

      <div style="
            flex: 1 1 0px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
      </div>

      <div style="
            flex: 1 1 0px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div id="dut" style="flex: 1 1 0px;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const dut = window.document.getElementById("dut");
    const info = window.document.getElementById("info");
    const cb = () => info.innerHTML = `size of RED element: ${dut.offsetWidth} x ${dut.offsetHeight}`
    new ResizeObserver(cb).observe(dut)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Where I start to be puzzle...

If you takes one `<div>` element *(the red one tagged "dut")*, and you replace it with `<canvas>` you will get:

[image]

In other words the red element can't be shrinking under **"300x150"** here

We should be able to fix this with `min-height` and `min-width` (*which predate flex computation*):

```css
{
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

Results:

[image]

`width` is now correct, but why **not the height** ?!

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  body {
    padding-left: 30px
  }
  
  span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px
  }
  
  #dut {
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <span id="info"></span>
  <div style="
        background-color: gray;
        height: 200px;
        width: 50%;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;" onresize="onResize()">

    <div style="
            height:100%;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        ">

      <div style="
            flex: 1 1 0px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
      </div>

      <div style="
            flex: 1 1 0px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <canvas id="dut" style="flex: 1 1 0px;"></canvas>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const dut = window.document.getElementById("dut");
    const info = window.document.getElementById("info");
    const cb = () => info.innerHTML = `size of RED element: ${dut.offsetWidth} x ${dut.offsetHeight}`
    new ResizeObserver(cb).observe(dut)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### So Why ?

I'm thinking of a bunch of workaround (more or less ugly), but my question more on what is the root cause of this behavior ? In there a another css tag like `min-min-height` ?!?

I've notice that `min-min-height` which is equal to 150 pixels in my case actually depends on your browser, and also on canvas's `height` attribute *(and will be something in regard of `viewBox` attribute for `<svg>`)*

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) You can read:

> height
>
> The height of the coordinate space in CSS pixels. **Defaults to 150.**

and

> width
>
> The width of the coordinate space in CSS pixels. **Defaults to 300.**

You already found a way to counter the width since in the flexbox world element can shrink to fit their parent size on the main axis (using `flex-shrink` and by adding `min-width`) but there is no shrink effect on the cross axis and your code is equivalent to the following:

```css
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  body {
    padding-left: 30px
  }
  
  span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px
  }
  
  #dut {
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
  }
```

```html
  <span id="info"></span>
  <div style="
        background-color: gray;
        height: 200px;
        width: 50%;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;" onresize="onResize()">

    <div style="
            height:100%;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        ">

      <div style="
            flex: 1 1 0px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
      </div>

      <div style="
            flex: 1 1 0px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div id="dut" style="flex: 1 1 0px;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const dut = window.document.getElementById("dut");
    const info = window.document.getElementById("info");
    const cb = () => info.innerHTML = `size of RED element: ${dut.offsetWidth} x ${dut.offsetHeight}`
    new ResizeObserver(cb).observe(dut)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I replaced the canvas with a simple div having a dimension of 300x150. The width can shrink and the height can only trigger an overflow and will never shrink.

If you make the height 0 you will have what you want because we removed the height constraint and it now behave like a div (an empty div by default has no height)

```css
html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  body {
    padding-left: 30px
  }
  
  span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px
  }
  
  #dut {
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
  }
```

```html
<span id="info"></span>
  <div style="
        background-color: gray;
        height: 200px;
        width: 50%;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;" onresize="onResize()">

    <div style="
            height:100%;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        ">

      <div style="
            flex: 1 1 0px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
      </div>

      <div style="
            flex: 1 1 0px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <canvas id="dut" style="flex: 1 1 0px;" height=0></canvas>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const dut = window.document.getElementById("dut");
    const info = window.document.getElementById("info");
    const cb = () => info.innerHTML = `size of RED element: ${dut.offsetWidth} x ${dut.offsetHeight}`
    new ResizeObserver(cb).observe(dut)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

or `height:0;min-height:100%` inside the CSS and keep the intrinsic dimension unchanged and be able to draw inside your canvas.

```css
html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  body {
    padding-left: 30px
  }
  
  span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px
  }
  
  #dut {
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 0;
    height: 0;
    min-height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<span id="info"></span>
  <div style="
        background-color: gray;
        height: 200px;
        width: 50%;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;" onresize="onResize()">

    <div style="
            height:100%;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        ">

      <div style="
            flex: 1 1 0px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
      </div>

      <div style="
            flex: 1 1 0px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <canvas id="dut" style="flex: 1 1 0px;" ></canvas>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const dut = window.document.getElementById("dut");
    const info = window.document.getElementById("info");
    const cb = () => info.innerHTML = `size of RED element: ${dut.offsetWidth} x ${dut.offsetHeight}`
    new ResizeObserver(cb).observe(dut)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can even update the attribute like you want and it will behave the same:

```css
html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  body {
    padding-left: 30px
  }
  
  span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px
  }
  
  #dut {
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 0;
    height: 0;
    min-height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<span id="info"></span>
  <div style="
        background-color: gray;
        height: 200px;
        width: 50%;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;" onresize="onResize()">

    <div style="
            height:100%;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        ">

      <div style="
            flex: 1 1 0px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
      </div>

      <div style="
            flex: 1 1 0px;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <canvas id="dut" style="flex: 1 1 0px;" heght="600" width="600"></canvas>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const dut = window.document.getElementById("dut");
    const info = window.document.getElementById("info");
    const cb = () => info.innerHTML = `size of RED element: ${dut.offsetWidth} x ${dut.offsetHeight}`
    new ResizeObserver(cb).observe(dut)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't get it, if I write `height=0` I ends up with any empty buffer for the canvas, and hence no space to draw to draw anything right ?  

let's add a little content

```
const ctx = dut.getContext('2d')
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(0,0,100,0,2*Math.PI); /* radius = 100px */
ctx.fill()
ctx.stroke();
```

if (canvas height=100), I can see a quarter of my circle, and yes I can shrink up to "100px" (and 150 anymore), but height=50 or worse height=0, my drawing is cropped

Comment: @chtimi59 of course you will see nothing when adding height=0. I tried to explain the behavior your are having. I didin't focus on how to draw inside the canvas. In case you want to draw something you will need to set height;0 in the CSS and no as attribute

Comment: @chtimi59 check the updated, added another alternative

Comment: I've updated the original post based on your explaination, please correct me if my explaination (based on your comment) is not accurate

Comment: @chtimi59 both height:0;min-height:100% are use to remove the contraint, not only the height:0 ... height:0 will force the element to have a height:0 then min-height:100% will force it again to take all the available space so now the container will decide about the height

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete snippet (svg and canvas) based on the previous answer

Quote from @Termani Afif:

> `{ height:0; min-height:100% }` are both use to remove the contraint. It will force the element to have a `height:0`, then `min-height:100%` will force it again to take all the available space. So now the container will decide about the height

[image]

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  body {
    padding-left: 30px
  }
  
  span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px
  }
  
  #dut {
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 0;
    height: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
  
  #dut2 {
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 0;
    height: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <span id="info"></span>
  <div style="
              background-color: gray;
              height: 200px;
              width: 50%;
              resize: both;
              overflow: auto;" onresize="onResize()">

    <div style="
                  height:100%;
                  display:flex;
                  flex-direction: column;
              ">

      <div style="
                  flex: 1 1 0px;
                  display:flex;
                  flex-direction: row;
                  ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: chocolate;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
      </div>

      <div style="
                  flex: 1 1 0px;
                  display:flex;
                  flex-direction: row;
                  ">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <canvas id="dut" style="flex: 1 1 0px;" width=100 height=100></canvas>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 0px; background-color: gray;"></div>
        <svg id="dut2" style="flex: 1 1 0px;" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#a00" />
              </svg>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const dut = window.document.getElementById("dut");
    const info = window.document.getElementById("info");
    const cb = () => info.innerHTML = `size of RED element: ${dut.offsetWidth} x ${dut.offsetHeight}`
    new ResizeObserver(cb).observe(dut)

    const ctx = dut.getContext('2d')
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#a00";
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.stroke();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
</body>

</html>
```